# maven - how does it work? Missing some some jars

Tags: maven, myeclipse

I am trying to move my MyEclipes projects to maven. But of course there are problems. After creating a web priject I get missing jar files - about 5 
org.springframework.security jar files e.g. org.springframework.security.ldap-3.0.5.RELEASE

show as missing in the jar build path. They are not in the corresponding .m2 directory. I un-installed ME4S, and deleted .m2, which force .me to be rebuilt on re-install, but it has the same problem.

How do I fix this?

It would be very helpful to understand how the .m2 process works - where is this coming from and how is it controlled?

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. I found another option for the case where a maven project is showing the jar are missing. a) find the dirs of the missing jars in .m2 and delete the .lastUpdated file 
b) then Project->Maven4MyEclipse->Update dependencies

This will force an another attempt to load the file.

It looks like the maven plugin downloads the check sum value of each jar as a file but does not use it, meaning downloads fail silently. Ouch.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the MyEclipse part, but this seems to be a pure maven question.

Maven (2/3) uses the pom.xml. This file describe your project. In that file you should define a list of dependencies (which can have their own dependencies and so on).

Maven read the pom.xml and build the classpath accordingly using direct and transitive dependencies.

You can use the `mvn dependency:tree` command to see how your classpath is built.
More on the [plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into tree command, it sound helpful. The problem was, and is, that the jar files are not always loaded and you have to check the repository by hand to make sure they are there.